# how to configure mongodb for use with meteor (was: how to make meteor reactive to direct mongod changes)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Original question below so that first answer makes sense. But it turns out the real problem is that you need to configure mongodb for use with meteor if you create the db yourself instead of letting meteor do it.

Original question:

I'm building a meteor app that displays a list of items.  If I add or delete entries to a published list using the HTML app it is instantly reactive across all browser instances.  If however, I make a change to the database using the direct MongoDB API the browsers do not update right away.  (My actual scenario is for these entries to be published from a data source, not from the browser.)

The question is what do I need to do in this separate app, which is inserting data into mongo so that the meteor app sees the changes immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never would have figured this out without Jermey's answer and the comment about oplog.  In the end everything he said was true. The problem was that I had created a single node mongdb instance without turning on oplog. However, meteor requires that oplog be enabled to for reactivity to work properly.

Detailed descriptions of turning on oplog can be found at https://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/how-to-get-a-mongodb-oplog-without-a-full-replica-set/ or https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/setting-up-mongodb-oplog-tailing.

But here is a short self-contained version for Ubuntu:

First edit /etc/mongodb.conf and add

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  oplogSizeMB: 100
```

Then connect to the database with mongo and type

```
use local
rs.initiate()
```

Then before launching the meteor app set MONGO_URL to point to the remote DBS and set MONGO_OPLOG_URL to point to the local DBS on the remote.  For example:

```
export MONGO_URL="mongodb://mongohost:27017/simple"
export MONGO_OPLOG_URL="mongodb://mongohost:27017/local"
meteor run
```

Comment: Good chase-down on your problem!  You should accept this as the answer for sure.

Comment: I also needed to add my hostname to /etc/hosts. Type hostname to find what it is, then add 127.0.0.1 myhostname to the file. And restart MongoDB for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

### So long as you are:

1. Properly publishing the data
2. Are properly subscribed to the data
3. Your templating engine (Blaze, React) is displaying the data from the output variable in a reactive context

Everything should be fine.  Reactive everywhere - even from a `database update`.  This is the default behavior from Meteor.  Everything should *just work*.

---

To be extra clear: **You don't need to do *anything* to your other app which accesses the MongoDB**.

You could be editing the MongoDB by hand from the command line - and so long as you've hooked everything up like I've illustrated above - everything will work as if somebody put the data in using your Meteor App.  A MongoDB is a reactive source in Meteor, and because of [Meteor's Tracker](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md), Meteor will serve this data up reactively no matter how the database changes.  This is the **default** behavior.

---

### Show us your code:

If you share the code in question either here or as a link to Github I will edit my answer to point out why your code is not doing this.

---

### More reading:

I ***highly*** suggest that you take a moment and read the *entire* [tracker manual](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md) (I have).  This explains how Meteor "Reactivity" works and should teach you everything you need to know as to why your code isn't working.  It's actually quite an easy read, just a long one.  If after reading that, it is ***still*** not clear - I would be *happy* to have a skype conversation with you and explain what is happening in your code line by line.  What you're trying to do is actually quite easy in Meteor.

You can also go [read here](https://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-oplog-and-meteor/) to see how MongoDB's `oplog` communicates with Meteor to provide that crispy reactivity you're looking for.  As [stubilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280944/stubailo) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985711/how-to-make-meteor-reactive-to-direct-mongod-changes/41985971#comment71149648_41985971) a few moments ago.  If your MongoDB doesn't have an `oplog` setup, then meteor falls back to polling (which is obviously going to be slower).  (Thanks stubilo)

Comment: One possible problem is that the database doesn't have the oplog set up - in that case Meteor falls back to polling which is a bit slower.

Comment: For my test case I'm using the simple-todos tutorial example (using blaze).  I open two browser windows on the app and when I click the checkbox on one entry the other browser window immediately updates. However, when I run mongo on the command line and run, for example, db.tasks.update({ _id: "LPm85W9EypzH8xqEi" }, { $set: { checked: false }}), it takes several seconds for the browsers to update.  If it matters, I'm running mongodb on an AWS instance and i'm running the simple-todos app on a Macbook.

Comment: And I can see that in any case I have a bunch of reading to do :) Thanks for the pointers to the tracker and oplog docs.

Comment: That's curious.  I've been working with meteor for more than a year now and I've made probably north of 20 apps and all of them behave normally.  I also use an AWS instance (thank the heavens for `mup`).  I'm very busy today - but after about 8:00pm EST I could give you a few minutes if you want me to put my eyes on your project.   Also, the Meteor Tracker is just plain interesting.  I love learning new javascript patterns and the tracker is a good one to know - you'll be better for it.  The manual is easy to read also.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! I hope to have this figured out by 8PM but if not I may look you up.

Comment: Final piece of data: On AWS I have a raw mongo instance without meteor. I'm running meteor on the Macbook and using MONGO_URL to point to the AWS instance. I'm guessing oplog is probably involved here.